# Stating if a number from 1-100 is divisible by 3 or 4

Tags: python, math

I've been trying to create a program that prints a number from 1-100, and also states if the number can be divisible by 3 or 4.
This is my code so far...

```
for n in range(1,100):
    print(n)
    if n % 3:
        print("this number is divisible by 3")
    if n % 4:
        print("This number is divisible by 4")
```

Comment: You should add `not`.

Comment: you should be using `n%3==0` and `n%4==0`

Comment: "This is my code ..." And what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `if` statement checks the *truthiness* of the expression that follows.

An *integer* has truthiness `True` if it is *not* equal to zero. So if we want to calculate whether the number is dividable by `3` or `4` (or whatever number), we actually want to check the opposite: we want to check that `n` modulo `3` is zero, so we can add `not` which checks the truthiness and returns the opposite, so:

```
for n in range(1,100):
    print(n)
    if not n%3:
        print("this number is divisible by 3")
    if not n%4:
        print("This number is divisible by 4")
```

Comment: I tried using    n%3 == 0 to find out if it is divisible or not. The code works, but this works as well too. Thanks

Comment: @Dull_Pencil: sure, `n % 3 == 0` works as well. Personally I find the `not` approach more Pythonic, but this is more a matter of taste :)

Comment: modulus is actually the one case where I prefer using `== 0` over `not`.